# Remember me running after the Login Page loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, remember-me, autologin

I'm using remember me option in my login page.
If user checked remember me, I'm storing user's info. (in localstorage with crypted)
Everything OK and running. 
But if user opened login page again, application redirect main page **after showing the login page.**
I dont want to appear login page again.
How i fix this?

Thats my code (using in login)

```
        $(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
        LoginWithRemember();
    });
```

NOTE : Application runs with JqueryMobile

Answer (score 1):

Put this code at very top of your page :

```
<html>
     <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if(localStorage.getItem('youRememberMeVariable') &&
               localStorage.getItem('yourRememberMeVariable')=='yourRememberMeValue')
                       window.location='http://yoursite.com/yourMainPage.';
        </script>
     </head>
       ....REST of the page ...
</html>
```

Remember that `localStorage` is only available only in sub-domain it has been saved.

Comment: This is faster than my code but still showing login.

Comment: If you insist to handle redirect in client side the answer looks like this (you can also cover the login page with an empty div) . But the ultimate solution should be taking care in server side.